# Asign intermediate Results in DataFrame Chain

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a `DataFrame` which I want to process with the help of a `@chain`. How can store intermediate results?

```
using DataFrames, Chain

df = DataFrame(a = [1,1,2,2,2], b = [1,2,3,4,5])

5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      1
   2 │     1      2
   3 │     2      3
   4 │     2      4
   5 │     2      5
```

@chain df begin
do stuff
save some intermediate result
do more stuff
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the intermediate results to a variable using `@aside`, pre-declaring it with `local` if it doesn't exist in the current scope already.

```
julia> function asidedemo(df)
            local y
            newdf = @chain df begin
                @rsubset(:a == 1)
                # store the intermediate results
                @aside y = _.b
                # and continue with other stuff
                @select(:a, :c = :a + :b)
            end

            @show(y)
            newdf
        end
asidedemo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> asidedemo(df)
y = [1, 2]
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      c     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      2
   2 │     1      3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution:

```
using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta, Chain

df = DataFrame(a = [1,1,2,2,2], b = [1,2,3,4,5])

@chain df begin
    @rsubset(:a == 1)
    @aside global x = _.b
end
```

So, this is actually really cool and gives a lot of possibilities. But is there any way to make this work inside a function? If you were to use the `global` keyword inside a function it would create the object in the global environment - which is not ideal.

Comment: You can pretty much do the same thing in a function too. Instead of a `global` inside the chain, declare the variable as a `local` variable before the chain: `function asidetest(df); local y; @chain df begin @rsubset(:a == 1); @aside y = _.b; end; @show(y); end` prints `y = [1, 2]`, and `y` remains a local variable scoped to the function.

Comment: Oh, that is an awesome response. Just make it an answer, so other readers can directly benefit.